# Calling Play Framework API by PHP

Tags: php, api, service, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been given a web application developped with Play Framework. 
They said that it can be called as a service and has its own API.

Although I have the files I know nothing about Play Framework. They told me to check a file which looks like this:

```
# Authentication
POST     /api/v1/session.json                                                controllers.base.Application.keepAlive()
DELETE   /api/v1/session.json                                                controllers.base.Application.logout()
POST     /api/v1/session/login.json                                          controllers.base.Application.login(redirectTo: String ?= null, isGuest: Boolean ?= false)
```

I want to call this service with PHP.  Is it possible? Or should I call it with using Play Framework?

I dont know anything about Play.

I am trying to call it like:

```
$data = array("redirectTo" => "", "isGuest" => true );

$url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/session/login.json';

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'content' => json_encode( $data ),
   'header'=> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
               "Accept: application/json\r\n"
   )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );
```

But PHP says:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:9000/api/v1/session/login.json?redirectTo=''&amp;isGuest=true): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

The application runs on my local system.

Thanks

Comment: Warning says url is not true, What is the result when you go to http://localhost:9000/api/v1/session/login.json on your browser? And  params you add at the end of url true? And you are making get request to POST handler.

Comment: I edited my api call still failed to open stream warning. When I call it in browser it says Action not found for GET. But now i am doing as POST.

Comment: You can do that with php-curl. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564811/calling-play-framework-api-by-php/23565054#23565054)

Comment: Before trying to access this API via code, can you check if the API is accessible through some REST client? For example you can try Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) REST tester client. See if you aren't missing anything. May be this API requires basic authentication header etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make curl requests to that services with a custom function;

```
/**
* @url your api url
* @method POST,GET,DELETE
* @params if your request method post, you can send array with key=>value
*
*/
function callApi($url, $method, $params = null) {
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($method == "POST") {
        foreach($params as $key=>$value) { 
            $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
        }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    } else if ($method == "GET") {

    } else if ($method == "DELETE") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

example usage;

```
callApi("http://localhost:9000/api/v1/session/login.json", "POST", array("username" => "john", "password" => "ssshhh")); //POST
callApi("http://localhost:9000/api/v1/session.json", "DELETE"); // DELETE
```